# AWS DMS task error for Aurora PostgreSQL migration

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, aws-dms, amazon-aurora

I am trying to migrate all the data present in my old RDS Aurora PostgreSQL cluster to the new RDS Aurora PostgreSQL cluster using AWS DMS. I have created the source and target endpoints and tested the connection successfully. However when I am trying to create a migration task in DMS, it is continuously failing with the error:

```
Last Error ODBC general error. Error executing command; Stream component failed at subtask 0, 
component st_0_PWDKKAMFPUY2RHV ; Stream component 
'st_0_PWDKKAMFPUY2RHV' terminated [reptask/replicationtask.c:3171] [1022502] 
Stop Reason RECOVERABLE_ERROR Error Level RECOVERABLE
```

Even after enabling CloudWatch logs, I am not able to figure out what's missing? What does the error signify or what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can't you just restore from snapshot to new cluster?

Comment: @Marcin no, I need synchronous data migration. All data changes to the source database that occur during the migration need to continuously replicate to the target.

Answer (score 0):

I had faced the same error and the issue seems related to database user rights for
Replication Client and Replication Slave

I have fixed it by setting the Replication rights using the below statements in SQL

```
GRANT REPLICATION CLIENT ON *.* to {dbusername}@'%';

GRANT REPLICATION SLAVE ON *.* to {dbusername}@'%';
```

**Note:** replacing {dbusername} with the actual database user name which was being used in DMS Endpoint

Comment: Check equivalent statements for PostgreSQL, I don't know PostgreSQL.